# How dynamically initialise object in Swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, objective-c-runtime

I use below line of code to allocate an Object(Suppose my Object name is Car) dynamically.

```
[self initliazieObject:[Car class]]

- (id)initliazieObject:(Class)model{

    id record = [[model alloc] init];
    return record;
}
```

How I can do this in swift 3.

Comment: @Phillip Mills thanks for editing

Answer (score 4):

Exactly as in Objective-C. Try this in a playground:

```
class Car : NSObject {}
func factory(type:NSObject.Type) -> NSObject {
    return type.init()
}
let c = factory(type:Car.self)
print(type(of:c)) // Car
```

(We can get fancy and do clever things with generics or `Self` to specify the type of the returned object more precisely, but my goal in this code is simply to do things the dumb way, just like Objective-C.)

Comment: Good answer brother:-)

Comment: "in a playground"?? Who are you and what have you done with the real matt? :)